# SQL MERGE statement not case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-sensitive, sql-merge

I have the following `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE TargetTable t
USING SourceTable s ON (t.ID = s.ID)

WHEN MATCHED 
     AND EXISTS (SELECT s.Day, s.Date, s.Name
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT t.Day, t.Date, t.Name)
    THEN UPDATE 
         SET t.Day = s.Day,
             t.Date = s.Date,
             t.Name = s.Name

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (ID, Day, Date, Name)
         VALUES (s.ID, s.Day, s.Date, s.Name);
```

There are more columns however I just shorten it for ease of reading.

So when I run this it works fine except: if I change the case of something in source table, it does not get updated in the target table. I believe this is solved by using COLLATE for UTF8 however cannot figure it out.

EDIT: What I mean by if I change something in the source table is: For testing purposes I will execute the MERGE, then change a varchar field but only the case of a letter. Then when I run MERGE again that change does not get propagated to the target table as it does not see that as a change IE it is case insensitive

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that after executing this `MERGE` once, you expect that updates to `SourceTable` will be automatically reflected in `TargetTable`?  That is simply incorrect.  If that's not what you mean, please provide more details on what you are doing, what results you expect, and what results you get.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Edited to clarify per comments.  Basically the MERGE statement EXISTS/EXCEPT portion is case insensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case-sensitive collation to qualify your columns.

Suppose your varchar columns were defined with a case-insensitive collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (explicitly, or by way of default for the database). Your subquery with EXCEPT would become:

```
SELECT s.Day, s.Date, s.Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
EXCEPT
SELECT t.Day, t.Date, t.Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

The `CS` in the collation's name stands for case-sensitive. The `CI` for case-insensitive.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. If I change just 1 letter case it does not update in the target table when I run the merge statement

Comment: @Pearl Hi Pearl. Then I suggest that you modify your question to include a sample data set that demonstrates the problem. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for a description on how to do that. Without that sample data set, it's hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: I have it working correctly now but I had to alter the table's COLLATION to Latin1_General_CS_AS. Changing it in the MERGE statement had no effect

Comment: Hello Pearl. Happy you got it working. Note that I focused only on the `Name` column as I was pretty sure its type is `(N)VARCHAR`. Perhaps you simply needed to change the collation of the other columns you selected as well (assuming their type is also `(N)VARCHAR`). You would do so by appending `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` as I did for the `Name` column.

Comment: Arg, You are exactly right. To many things on the go, thanks for your help:)